# Vague error in log "You do not have permission to access this page."

Tags: permissions

What's the first step to finding out the cause of an issue logged in ConfigAndLog/.log? (shown below).. Its from a shortcode on the frontend of wordpress 4.4.7 [civicrm component="user-dashboard" hijack="0"].

Civi 4.6.4

The page works fine but someone somewhere in the world might not have been able to access their dashboard:

```
Feb 09 11:41:08  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => You do not have permission to access this page.
    [code] => 
)


Feb 09 11:41:08  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(363): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/WordPress.php(294): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("You do not have permission to access this page.")
#2 /home/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(277): CRM_Utils_System_WordPress->permissionDenied()
#3 /home/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(232): CRM_Utils_System::permissionDenied()
#4 /home/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#5 /home/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#6 /home/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1189): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#7 /home/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.shortcodes.php(292): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#8 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Shortcodes->render_single((Array:2), "", "civicrm")
#9 /home/public_html/www/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(326): call_user_func((Array:2), (Array:2), "", "civicrm")
#10 [internal function](): do_shortcode_tag((Array:7))
#11 /home/public_html/www/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(223): preg_replace_callback("/\[(\[?)(civicrm)(?![\w-])([^\]\/]*(?:\/(?!\])[^\]\/]*)*?)(?:(\/)\]|\](?:([^\...", "do_shortcode_tag", "[civicrm component=\"user-dashboard\" hijack=\"0\"]")
#12 /home/public_html/www/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.shortcodes.php(200): do_shortcode("[civicrm component=\"user-dashboard\" hijack=\"0\"]")
#13 [internal function](): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Shortcodes->prerender(Object(WP))
#14 /home/public_html/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(601): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
#15 /home/public_html/www/wp-includes/class-wp.php(692): do_action_ref_array("wp", (Array:1))
#16 /home/public_html/www/wp-includes/functions.php(952): WP->main("")
#17 /home/public_html/www/wp-blog-header.php(14): wp()
#18 /home/public_html/www/index.php(17): require("/home/public_html/www/wp-blog-header.php")
#19 {main}
```

For example, this is an error in the production log but how do I know 'who' in the world or which constituent ran into the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this extension

https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-error-handler

> Sometimes CiviCRM can be real tough to debug. Especially when you are getting fatal errors, but only by some users, and you can't recreate the problems. This utility will send you a detailed email when a CiviCRM fatal error occurs.

Comment: FYI, it may be this is the correct link: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-error-report-handler